# Issue with Responsive DataTables And Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, datatables

I want to use Datatables and Responsive extension inside Bootstrap Tabs. I have this working separately.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    } );
    $('#exampleInTab').DataTable( {
        responsive: true
    } );
} );

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
        .columns.adjust()
        .responsive.recalc();
});
```

You can see the issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vjt8azd0/)

Comment: I can't see what the problem is, could you explain a little more?

Comment: Yes of course. There are two tables: one inside second tab and other at bottom (outside of tabs). Bottom table works fine if you resize window, table of tab doesn't.

Comment: You can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanoc/ebRXw/) a responsive datatable

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### CAUSE

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. Bootstrap library is included before jQuery library
2. API method `responsive.recalc()` is available in `dataTables.responsive.js` since `1.0.1`, you're including version `1.0.0`.
3. Event handler should be attached once DOM is available.

#### SOLUTION

1. Include Bootstrap library after jQuery library
2. Include [Responsive](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/) extension version 1.0.1 or later
3. Use the code below:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('#example').DataTable({
           responsive: true
       });

       $('#exampleInTab').DataTable({
           responsive: true
       });

       $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
           $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
              .columns.adjust()
              .responsive.recalc();
       });    
   });
   ```

#### DEMO

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjt8azd0/51/) for code and demonstration.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables and Bootstrap Tabs.

Comment: Thank you Gyrocode. I thought that as bottom table was working resources were valid... It were OK in my real code... but I had other error in my javascript in the call to adjust() function

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers above but none worked. I was using JQuery Steps Wizard as tabs. I had to use `$('#datatable').css("width", '100%')` as well for it to work.

```
wizard.steps({
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            enableFinishButton: false,
            enablePagination: false,
            enableAllSteps: true,
            titleTemplate: "#title#",
            cssClass: "tabcontrol",
            onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {

                if (currentIndex == 2) {
                    $('#datatable').css("width", '100%')
                    $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
                }
            }
        })
```

My Datatable is on the 3rd tab hence the check on the `currentIndex`.