# Responsive DataTables Is Not Working in Bootstrap Tab

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/os0n9e5p/) and let me know why the DataTable is not functioning on

I already tries adding

```
$($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
```

after the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'csv'
    ]
} );


} );
```

but it didnt fix the issue!

Comment: What is not functioning? The dataTable works?

Comment: As you can see in the Demo the DataTable is working! I am not getting the responsive format!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with Responsive DataTables And Bootstrap Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690478/issue-with-responsive-datatables-and-bootstrap-tabs)

Comment: As @Gyrocode.com said, it was down to having to initialize the datatable when it becomes visible - http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/os0n9e5p/3/